# Report Validation by Row

Tags: excel

Problem: Tasked with having users validate their reports.  Users have to have their reports validated against a master report file.  If their data exist within the report its valid.

Master Report Example:
[image]

User Report Example:

[image]

If the entire row of cell data exist then the row entry is valid, if not than not valid.

Task 2: If not valid row entry, identify which cells make the entry invalid.

Resolutions: Have attempted using countifs statements but did not result in away to identify which cell was making invalid, just if the entire row entry was valid.

Comment: Can anyone point me in best direction to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "User Report" is Sheet2 & "Master Report" is Sheet1, with "PO" located in A1.

is Sheet2, cell E2 :

```
=IF(A2="","",IFERROR(MATCH(1,INDEX((A2=Sheet1!A:A)*(B2=Sheet1!C:C)*(C2=Sheet1!F:F)*(D2=Sheet1!G:G),0,1),0),"NOT OK"))
```

and drag downwards.

Idea : based on the same logic as the last formula [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria) , iferror will output "NOT OK" if no match is found.

Please share if it work/understandable/not. ( :